# Programmatically navigating in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a react application where I use react-router-dom to set up my client routes as follows in my app.js file:

```
<Route path="/admin" element={<AdminLayout />}>
    <Route index path="add-article" element={<AddArticleForm />} />
    <Route path="success" element={<Success />} />
</Route>
```

In my AddAritcleForm component, I would like to programmatically navigate to /admin/success when there is a successful response from the server. Please see below:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AddArticleForm = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target;

    try {
      const request = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/add-article', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          url: form.url.value,
          title: form.title.value,
          author: form.author.value,
          section: form.section.value,
          content: form.content.value,
          tags: form.tags.value,
          excerpt: form.excerpt.value,
        }),
      });

      const response = await request.json();

      if (response) {
        console.log(response);
        navigate('/admin/success');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      //   Handle error
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Create New Article</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...jsx code...
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default AddArticleForm;
```

I can see in my backend console that the response is sent properly, but for some reason, the navigate() function is not navigating to /admin/success after receiving the response. **What might be the reason that react-router-dom is not navigating upon receiving the response?**

Comment: Does AdminLayout have an `Outlet`?

Comment: Yes AdminLayout does have an Outlet

Comment: Is `response` a truthy value? `response` being falsey is the only way I see your code not reaching the `navigate('/admin/success');` call. I see no overt issues in the code you've shared. If possible, think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a test example that may help:
https://playcode.io/1501535

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom" ;
import { Home } from './Home.jsx';
import { Admin } from './Admin.jsx';
import { Success } from './Success.jsx';

export function App() {
 return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Home />} >
                  <Route path='Admin' element={<Admin />}>  
                   <Route path='Success' element={<Success />}/>  
                  </Route>
                </Route>
                
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
}

// Log to console
console.log('Hello console')
```

Home.jsx

```
import { useNavigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

export function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
 
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Home</h1>
            <button onClick={() => navigate("/Admin")}>test</button>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Admin.jsx

```
import { useNavigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
export function Admin() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Admin</h1>
            <button onClick={() => navigate("/Admin/Success")}>test</button> 
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );}
```

Success.jsx

```
export function Success() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Success</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't wrap a  tags with a parent . It is simplest to just have 2 separate tags:

```
<Route path="/admin/add-article" element={<AddArticleForm />} />
<Route path="/admin/success" element={<Success />} />
```

Comment: yes path="/admin/success"  that would be correct so ur navigation should work

Comment: Nested routes are perfectly valid `react-router` component syntax. This answer is your subjective opinion and omits the `AdminLayout` layout component the OP is using. This answer also doesn't address the issue of navigation to the routes, so it's better as a comment if all you really have to say is something about the route organization.

Comment: @DrewReese I never said they weren’t valid. There doesn’t seem to be any other issues with the code provided, hence why I answered with an alternate routing structure. However, I accept that it could have just been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const AdminLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>AdminLayout</h1>
       ....


      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};
```

Add Outlet at the end.

**refer** ->

- https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/
- https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet